# How can I write holiday list to a file?

Tags: files

In Emacs I can evaluate the following to get a list of holidays:

```
(list-holidays 2020 2021)
```

But I need to have the list written to a file. I have tried this:

```
(progn (list-holidays 2020 2021) (write-file \"myholidays.txt\"))
```

But no luck.
How can I write the holiday list to a file?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

`list-holidays` opens a new buffer called `*Holidays*` and makes it visible, but leaves the current buffer unchanged. Meanwhile `write-file` writes the contents of the current buffer to a file. Thus your code writes the wrong thing to the file. You can call `switch-to-buffer` to change which buffer is current, but you probably also want to restore the window configuration afterwards.

You probably want to do something like this:

```lisp
(save-window-excursion
  (list-holidays 2020 2021)
  (switch-to-buffer "*Holidays*")
  (write-file "~/temp/myholidays.txt"))
```

`save-window-excursion` saves the current window configuration, runs the code you give it just like progn would, then restores the window configuration. It also saves the state of the buffer you are in as well (point and mark and suchlike).

The code inside opens the holidays window, switches to it, and then writes it to a file.

Edit: Incidentally, I took a peek at the `list-holidays` function before writing my answer, because as lawlist says there could be a better function to use. Ideally there would be one that returns a string, or just puts the text in the current buffer. Sadly no such function exists, though it wouldn’t be terribly hard to split the current `list-holidays` in half if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a built-in function similar to `list-holidays` that returns the list as a string.  If no such function exists, then I would be inclined to take the function `list-holidays` and modify it to suit my needs ... beginning by typing `M-x find-function RET list-holidays RET` and copying the function to a `*scratch*` buffer and modifying it accordingly.  However, I saw what makes it tick and see that the output is to a buffer defined as the `holiday-buffer` -- as such, the following may suffice to meet the needs of the O.P. without further ado:

```lisp
(save-window-excursion
  (require 'holidays) ;; just in case it is not already loaded 
  (when (get-buffer holiday-buffer)
    (with-current-buffer holiday-buffer
      (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
        (erase-buffer))))
  (list-holidays 2020 2021)
  (with-temp-file "/Users/HOME/Desktop/myholidays.txt"
    (insert-buffer holiday-buffer))
  (kill-buffer holiday-buffer))
```